# How to Delegate the Session from One service to another Service

Tags: java, web-services, session, servlets

i am new to service and java.i will explain my workflow.

Client will call one synchronous service to service 1. service 1  do some operation and will delegate the session to service 2.then service 1 become free and ready to do some other work.service 2  do some operation and response back to client. is this possible like delegate the work to some other service and reply back to client. below Diagram makes you more clear.

[image]

in servlet we can redirect the response (response.sendredirect(url)) to some url like service or html page.but i think that response just redirect to some different url not the session right. so i want to know whether above workflow is possible ? if its possible please give some piece of code or ref link .

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequestDispatcher class to forward the request to service 2;

`RequestDispatcher rd = context_object.getRequestDispatcher('url to service 2');`

`rd.forward(request, response);`

Inside service 2, you can use

`request_object.getSession();`

 to get the original session object

Comment: sorry for the late reply.from where will get the contex_object. ServletContext contex_object=request.getServletContext();like this.i am using rest service not servlet. above code gives null exception.i tried to use request.getRequestDispatcher("url2").but this also giving null exception in RequestDispatcher. can u give some more idea..